# How to pass Images path from AJAX call to div Tag

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have AJAX Response  for this call

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $.ajax({
        url  : '<%=getChartData%>',
        success : function(data){

            document.write(data);

             $.each(data, function(index, item) {

                 $('img').attr('src',data.item);


              });


        }
    });

});
</script>

[E:\li\1.jpg,E:\li\2.jpg,E:\li\10.jpg]   (**AJAX Response** )
```

With the Obtained response shown above , i am trying to replace all my img tags to contain the above dynamic source .

But this isn't working , could anybody please help me .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the returned data is an array, and I assume you already know that there is a drive letter included in each result, and if it's not supposed to be there you will have to remove it. Something like this should insert the images in the first ten image tags ?

```
$.ajax({
    url  : '<%=getChartData%>',
    success : function(data){
       $.each(data, function(index, item) {
          $('img').eq(index).attr('src', item);
       });
    }
});
```

Comment: The returned data is in this format [E:\li\1.jpg,E:\li\2.jpg,E:\li\10.jpg] ,  what should the img declartion should be initially ?? before the ajax response ?

Comment: Well, yes! That sure looks like a javascript array, and probably works like one as well :) All you have to do is iterate over the array, or you could iterate over img tags, but I would prefer the former, and insert the images into the img tags src attribute. If the source really is "E:\path\image.jpg" your golden. Usually images have relative or absolute paths, with domains and such, not drive letters, but that's up to you to figure out, not much we can do other than guess based on what is normally done ?

Comment: ya i can figure out the drive path , i ran with your code  the images are not displayed (alt value is coming ) where can i put alert an check , i will update my question in few secs

Comment: Use the browser console and check the source to see what changed into what.

Comment: Its saying Not allowed to load local resource: file:///E:/liferaytomcat/liferay-portal-6.1.0-ce-b4/tomcat-7.0.22/Uploaded%20Files/190420120611171146Wj.jpg

Comment: This is the reponse 23:51:19,203 INFO  [PortalImpl:4678] Current URL /[ generates exception: null
23:51:19,312 INFO  [PortalImpl:4678] Current URL /l generates exception: null
23:51:19,312 INFO  [PortalImpl:4678] Current URL /p generates exception: null
23:51:19,343 INFO  [PortalImpl:4678] Current URL /U generates exception: null

Comment: Yep, that's because it's a path to the local filesystem. You'll have to refference it relative to your website and the folder it is in there. It will probably be somewhat similar to what you have, but like all files on your website it either needs to be a relative path, like `/websiteroot/somepath/image.jpg` or an absolute path like `http://mysite.com/websiteroot/somepath/image.jpg`

Comment: Agree , now i chnaged the code to get only the relative path . please see the updated alert in my question .

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this could help you:

```
var i = 0;
$("img").each(function(){
    if(data[i])
        $(this).attr("src", data[i++])
})
```